# Open dyslexic font

Tags: fonts

Is it straight forward to use the [OpenDyslexic font](http://opendyslexic.org/) in a latex document? What steps would be required?

Comment: The original Dyslexie font is now free for home use
Download it for free at http://www.dyslexiefont.com/

Answer (score 11):

As it is distributed as a TrueType font, you can use it without difficulty with either `xetex` or `luatex`.  Here's a sample using LuaLaTeX that I wrote when the font was first announced.  The lua code came from somewhere on this site (probably from the Cthulu question, but I don't remember off the top of my head).  I sent the result to the author of the font who was, fortunately, amused by it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Open Dyslexic}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%create a lua script file
\begin{filecontents*}{luaFunctions.lua}

function createReplaceTable()    
    replaceTable = {}

    -- create a table with all ASCII chars
    -- the name and(!) the value of each table item is the ASCII char
    -- this is important if the char shouldn't be replaced
    -- the table have 128 items each filled with the corresponding char
    for i = 1, 128, 1 do    
       replaceTable[string.char(i-1)] = string.char(i-1)
    end
end

function parseString(input)
    outputString = ""

    -- for each char in the given string we replace
    -- the char with the content of the table item
    -- because the table items have the same name like the chars
    -- we have access to the table item via the given char
    for i = 1, string.len(input) do
        char = input:sub(i, i)
        outputString = outputString..rotateString(char)
    end

    tex.print(outputString)
end

function parseFile(fileName)
    -- open file
    local input = io.open('lorem.txt', 'r')

    -- parse each line
    for line in input:lines() do
        parseString(line)
    end
end

function rotateString(c)
    if c == " " then
      return c
    end
    local ang = math.random(-10,10)
    local dp = math.random(-.5,.5)
    return "\\raisebox{" .. dp .. "pt}{\\rotatebox[origin=c]{" .. ang .. "}{" .. c .. "}}"
end

function fillReplaceTable()
    -- here we fill/override the replacements for each ASCII char
    replaceTable["L"] = "\\textbf{\\large L}\\marginpar{\\tiny 'L'(\\stepcounter{counterForL}\\#\\thecounterForL)}"
    replaceTable["o"] = "\\underline{o}"
    replaceTable["e"] = ""
end

\end{filecontents*}    

% read the external lua file to declare the functions,
% but without execute the Lua commands and functions
\directlua{dofile("luaFunctions.lua")}

%create and fill the tables
\directlua{createReplaceTable()}
\directlua{fillReplaceTable()}

% latex commands to execute the lua functions
\def\parseString#1{\directlua{parseString("#1")}}
\def\parseFile#1{\directlua{parseFile("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\parseString{%
This is the Open Dyslexia font.
Allegedly, it was designed so that the letters have a `gravity' to them which helps to anchor them to the baseline and thus prevent them jumping about on the page (this being one of the ways that dyslexia can show itself).
I'm not so sure that it's working.
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Open Dyslexic font with lualatex]

(Added in edit) Speravir (in the comments) is absolutely correct: most of the above is to achieve the random rotation effect.  Using the font without that is simple: install it somewhere that TeX can find it, use the package `fontspec`, set the font to `Open Dyslexic` (read the fontspec manual for details about font names and the difference between `xelatex` and `lualatex`), and compile with either `xelatex` or `lualatex`.  The following is a smaller example (compiled with `lualatex`).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153778/86}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Open Dyslexic}

\begin{document}
This is the Open Dyslexia font.
Allegedly, it was designed so that the letters have a `gravity' to
them which helps to anchor them to the baseline and thus prevent them
jumping about on the page (this being one of the ways that dyslexia
can show itself).
I'm not so sure that it's working.
\end{document}
```

[image: More normal document with the Open Dyslexia font]

Comment: Note for the OP: Most of this example is fun. You only need to load the package `fontspec` in some way (explicitely like Andrew did or implicitely by loading other packages, which load it themselves) and the line `\setmainfont{Open Dyslexic}`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks reasonably easy to convert my pdftex document to lualatex. I imagine the fonts installed on my windows machine will generally be automatically available to lualatex. I presume this response implies that using open dyslexic in pdftex itself is either not possible or stratightforward.

Comment: @Chogg There are ways to get a truetype font to work in pdftex, but I think that they basically involve converting the font from TTF to TeX's known format.  It's much easier just to use luatex or xetex.

Comment: @Chogg You can use truetype fonts with pdftex without converting them. This works fine but it is not straightforward. Or, rather, the truetype bit is straightforward but generating the support files is complicated in the case of truetype, just as it is in the case of type1, metafont etc. `fontinst` can automate some of this but it is still not straightforward. You cannot use truetype with regular (non-pdf) tex without conversion, however.