# !Package fontspec Error: The font "OpenDyslexic" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, errors, fontspec

Im trying to use the fontspec package to change my output font to dyslexic freindly font "OpenDyslexic" which according to this pdf does exist in fontspec: https://es.overleaf.com/articles/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc . However i havent been able to get any of the fonts listed in that doc (or from original name used in the code) to work using xelatex, all giving the same error when, and only some will load using lualatex (such as QTFuture,Montserrat)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153778/86}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OpenDyslexic}

\begin{document}

This is the Open Dyslexia font.
Allegedly, it was designed so that the letters have a `gravity' to
them which helps to anchor them to the baseline and thus prevent them
jumping about on the page (this being one of the ways that dyslexia
can show itself).
I'm not so sure that it's working.
\end{document}
```

I copied this code from a similar quetion from 6 years ago and it seemed to work for other people at the time so I assume i must be using the fontsec package wrong in some way or maybe in dont have the right fonts installed somehow.

Im using Win10, MikTex 2.9 and TeXmaker, fontspec folder is in: C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec not sure if that helps at all

ive also tried using fonts from this list from consol: fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n"
which gives a massive list with many repeats of names such as Computer Modern and Euler and im not really sure how to seach such a list in consol. (a few of these also work using lualatex but not xelatex: Informal Roman & Papyrus both work)

Comment: I believe the page you linked indicates that the listed fonts are available on Overleaf, "A sampler of the OTF/TTF fonts installed on Overleaf...", not necessarily in an installation of Tex Live or MikTex. I do not have such a font in my installation of MacTex.

Comment: It appears to be freely downloadable here: https://opendyslexic.org. I can't advise on how to install a font on a Windows system, however.

Comment: ok thank you, i just assumed that it was just all included in the fontspec package, not just native to overleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you should [download the file,](https://opendyslexic.org/) and install it for all users (as an Administrator).  Installing it as a regular user will not work.

If you need it for just one project, you can save it in the project folder.  You could also create a local TeX tree and put it there.  However, just installing the font for all users is simpler.

Comment: yeah as soon as i did that it work fine with the code, i only needed to install the font and LaTeX picked it up immediately