# Math parts with OpenDyslexic font

Tags: fonts, luatex, math-fonts

Invoking `lualatex`, I managed to make all plain text displayed with the Open Dyslexic font (latest release 0.910.12-rc2 installed) by following the [steps described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153778/open-dyslexic-font). After reading this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360406/using-math-fonts-in-lualatex), I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} %% Why is this package needed?
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont{OpenDyslexic}
\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic} %% Unfortunately not enough

\begin{document}

Any dyslexia math fonts out there?

Given $\Delta = b^2 - 4 ac$, we have 
\[ r_{\pm} = \frac{- b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.\]

\end{document}
```

However, all mathematical parts are still displayed with the usual TeX math fonts.
Indeed, I have the following warnings:

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "OpenDyslexic" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Math".
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'OpenDyslexic' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'OpenDyslexic' with script
(fontspec)
```

Before a direct support for math or at least a Math variant is available, how can I make use of the existing letters in math mode?

Comment: that is a text font, not a math font, it misses an important table. so you can't use it generally for math. You could use a math font as starter and replace some letters with your font.

Comment: I know I need a workaround for now. And how could I replace/display just the letters in math mode with the ones from this font?

Comment: By the way, you need `unicode-math` for the `\setmathfont` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to override only the letters of your math font, with `range=`.  OpenDyslexic doesn’t have math symbols or an OpenType math table, so you have to load a math font first, and then override only the letters and numerals with OpenDyslexic.  You might try something like this. (Warning: I don’t have the font, so this is untested.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Report an error if a font does not have a symbol.

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Ligatures=TeX,
                      Scale=MatchUppercase }

\setmainfont{OpenDyslexic}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Fira Math} % Or maybe try KPMath-Sans?
\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic Italic}[range=it/{Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic}[range=up/{Latin,latin,num}]

\begin{document}

Any dyslexia math fonts out there?

Given $\Delta = b^2 - 4 ac$, we have 
\[ r_{\pm} = \frac{- b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.\]

\end{document}
```

If OpenDylexic contains Greek letters, you could remove the `/{Latin,latin,num}` restrictions.  If you also want to use its basic symbols, like plus and times signs, you could try changing `range=up/{Latin,latin,num}` to  `range={"01-"FF,up/{Latin,latin,num}}`

If you don’t want slanted letters in math mode, load `unicode-math` with the option

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
```

##### P.S.

The above sample will only load letters and digits from OpenDyslexic. To load other symbols, you would add them to the `range=` option.  For example, this demonstrates several ways to use the OpenDyslexic version of math operators:

```
\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic}[range={up/{Latin,latin,num},"2B,"2D,\cdot,`×}]
```

Any symbols without an override like that are loaded from Fira Math.  There are, however, some symbols Fira Math does not have, such as, I believe, ⬜ (U+2B1C, `\lgwhtsquare`).  You can load these from some other font instead, for example:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range=\lgwhtsquare]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check KPMath-Sans but anyway I'm not sure of what exactly I should set :( The Wikipedia page links to studies that are not conclusive on the effects of these fonts. The best I can do is trying to reuse most of the existing OpenDyslexic symbols in math mode, starting with the letters (italic) and the numbers . BTW, I have many warnings.

Comment: I settled on `\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic}[range={"01-"FF,up}]` for the last part.

Comment: Can I see this fonts OpenDyslexic, please? I am curious :-) Best regards.

Comment: @greendiod Sounds good. Upright Greek letters might possibly not work.

Comment: @Davislor I stumbled upon a small problem when I used `\setmathfont{OpenDyslexic}[range={"01-"FF,up}]`. When I used the `cases` environment or a plain `\left\lbrace\ `, the brace didn't scale up. What is the exact meaning of `"01-"FF` in the above and how do I exclude all scaling symbols from being replaced?

Comment: @greendiod Oh, that might be a problem. You could look up any symbols you want to replace up on a Unicode table, and select them more carefully, like `range={"21,"2A-"2E,"3A-3F,"B1,"B7,"D7,"F7,up}`.  You can use, e.g. `\cdot` for `"B7` and `\times` for `"D7`, or backtick-`÷` for `"F7`, but you have to use hex notation for the minus sign. Or you can just go with `up` and use regular sans-serif math operators.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution but I can't get certain math symbols to work, like \Box. It saw the unicode is 2610. Is there way to render it in Open Dyslexic font?

Comment: @noir1993 Fira Math [lacks that particular symbol.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/firamath/firamath-specimen.pdf) You can load all such symbols by adding an additional command, which I’ll edit into the answer.

Comment: In this particular case, though, only symbols from [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) work with the `\setmathfont[range=...]` command.  There are a few workarounds for this, but perhaps the simplest is to define `\Box` as an alias for `\lgwhtsquare`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks. I used `\renewcommand{\Box}{\mdlgwhtsquare}`, note that Fira Math has a `\mdlgwhtsquare`, it did the trick. Thanks for the very useful links.